# Editing XML Source in BIRT plug-in for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, birt

I was trying to edit an XML node for a BIRT report using the XML source tab. When I clicked on the text, The editor scrolled to the top of the page. Does anyone know why the BIRT plug-in is doing this?

Comment: Are you using the latest versions?  Which versions are you using?

Comment: Eclipse: Kepler and Birt: 4.3.0

Comment: Worst cliche ever, but... have you tried restarting? I've had the same problem, it disappeared by itself upon restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Eclipse can get in some "Quick Access" edit mode. If you click inside the input box with a "Quick Access" watermark at the top, then you will be able to click inside the xml.

Thanks everyone for your input!